# Two Seagate external drives can't be seen simultaneously in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have two external Seagate drives. The first is Flash Drive (FreeAgent Drive)
and the second is (GoFlex drive) (USB 3.0).

I wanted to copy from one to the other while both were attached. They can't work together for some reasons. The one which was plugged first is shown (for example like: "J" drive) and the second is not shown at all but still visible from the Safely Remove and Eject MEdia tray, so I can eject them..

The system I'm running is Windows 7 64 bit and is up to date and I believe it's free from viruses according to Norton :D

They both are seen in the tray (Safely Remove and Eject Media).

They both work 100% seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copy and pasted from Seagate KnowledgeBase (Answer By Xmustanguyx)](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/FreeAgent-Products/Using-two-Externals-at-once-one-won-t-show-up/m-p/78798/message-uid/78798/highlight/true#U78798):

> I just got my 2TB FreeAgent GOFlex Desk and plugged it into laptop.
>   Formatted it works fine. Plugged my 500GB FreeAgent GO and NADA.
>   Swapped just as you all did and nothing, both worked independently and
>   would not work together.
>
> Here's what I did to fix:
>
> My system: Gateway with WIN7 64BIT Home Premium.
>
> Externals are USB.
>
> Right click "My Computer" then click "Manage", then navigate to "Storage" -> "Disk Management". Find the external that shows a drive
>   letter and change it to something else. (I don't think this is
>   necessary but you can change it to what you like after you get them to
>   work. This is what I did to get it to work.)
>
> Next, right-click the the drive that is not showing up, in my case I
>   changed the 500GB to N:\ and the disk showing was Disk 2 Basic1863.02
>   GB.
>
> Right click the GRAY area in the right hand side. Just under the red
>   arrow that is pointing down.
>                                                                                                                                               Under that you will see the error message if you hover over the HELP.
>   It says, at least on mine:
>
> > Offline (The disk is offline because it has a signature collision with another disk that is online)
>
> [image: Device man]
>
> Now that you right-clicked, it selects "ONLINE" and this will bring it
>   online and automatically assign another drive letter. At this point
>   you can change drive letters or whatever else.
>
> [image: different image]

The post at Seagate is 3/4 down the page, but the whole page is on the subject.